# How to remove all SubcriteriaList from projectionCriteria in Hibernate (Java) - prevent from using left join

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am working with Hibernate and dto,dao design patterns (Java).

i have an entity class and attribute in it and they are defined with  `@ManyToOne` annotation.

I would like to create a count query and "tell" hibernate  "DO NOT JOIN" with `@ManyToOne` tables

While creating a count query:

```
(Long) crit.setProjection(Projections.count("id")).uniqueResult();
```

The sql exceute by hibernate is with `left join` in it .

Even if i count **explicitly** on the `@Id` annotation  from the entity class .
The actual query appear is with LEFT JOIN for all the "other tables".

That SQL query build by Hibernate - is not efficient since there is no reason for creating a left join when `@ManyToOne` is set.

After trying and reading about hibernate i found out about FetchMode
but even when setting `FetchMode.LAZY`

```
.setFetchMode("brand", FetchMode.LAZY)
```

The Sql from hiberante having left join in it.

i have also attached the photo from debug that showing all the SubcriteriaList 
which is under projectionCriteria .

How could i tell Hibernate **DON'T** left join Tables from entity class ?
(without writing SQL query by myself)  ?

[image: This is where]

```
public Response findAll() {
    Criteria crit = getDtoCriteria();
}

public Criteria getDtoCriteria() {
    return getDtoCriteria(getDtoClass(), getSession());
}

public Criteria getDtoCriteria(Class clazz, Session session) {

    Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria(session);
    setProjecttionForDto(crit, true, clazz);
    return crit;
}
```

This all are my Subcriteria

```
[Subcriteria(bran*******ance:bran*******ance), Subcriteria(buc*****:buc*****), Subcriteria(br****:br****), Subcriteria(dyn***:dyn***), Subcriteria(dyna*****.user:user)]
```

Comment: just a thought: any chance of creating another entity without the manytoone join?

Comment: I am working with a build in "@Service , @Controller  etc..." having 2 Entity will not do any good .
i have the same problem for more than one entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FetchMode.SELECT` instead:

```
(Long) crit.setFetchMode("brand",FetchMode.SELECT)
           .setProjection(Projections.count("id"))
           .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: I have tried that:

(Long) crit.setFetchMode("br***", FetchMode.SELECT).setFetchMode("bra************nces", FetchMode.SELECT).setFetchMode("buc********ads", FetchMode.SELECT).setFetchMode("lz******bs", FetchMode.SELECT).setFetchMode("users", FetchMode.SELECT)
    .setProjection(Projections.count("id")).uniqueResult();


And the Sql from hibernate keep on creating the left outer join .
any other idea ?

Comment: well that's annoying... is it just joining to one table or is it joining to all 5 other tables?

Comment: All five table , 
will that could help ?

.createCriteria("d*****", JoinType.NONE)

Comment: Looks like a [code bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3538) actually. You could try an HQL query instead.